# Вызов приватного конструктора родителя при наследовании

Tags: java

Почему я в данной ситуации могу унаследоваться от класса `B`? Ведь у класса `B` единственный конструктор, и тот закрытый.

```
public class Test {
    class B {
        private B() {
        }
    }

    class C extends B {
    }
}

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.C b = new Test().new C();
    }
}
```

Несмотря на это я, как видите, могу создавать объекты класса `С`. Сразу скажу, что приватные методы и поля класса `B` класс-наследник `С` не видит, но каким-то образом видит приватный конструктор.

При этом не важно, имеют ли внутренние классы модификатор `static` или нет. Работает и так, и так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что классы `C` и `B` объявлены как внутренние классы в `Test`. Поэтому класс `C` вполне себе имеет доступ к приватному конструктору `B`, равно как и к `private`-методам `B`. Например, этот код прекрасно работает:

```
class B
{
    private B() {  }

    private void print() { System.out.println("B print"); }
}

class C extends B
{
    public void print() { super.print(); }
}
```

Если же эту "связь" между классами `B` и `C` убрать, например, разнеся их по разным файлам:

*B.java*:

```
public class B
{
    private B() { }
}
```

*C.java*:

```
public class C extends B { }
```

То возникнет ошибка компиляции:

> error: B() has private access in B
>   public class C extends B { }

Всё сводится к тому, что ошибка возникает только в случае, при котором в классе-наследнике нет возможности получить доступ ни к одному из конструкторов родителя. В вашем же случае такая возможность есть.

Comment: Странно, но у меня Ваш код не работает. Компилятор говорит, что у класса B нет конструктора по умолчанию, что логично, когда мы наследуем класс с единственным приватным конструктором. Ровно как и private поля и методы в примере, что я привел выше также из класса C не видны. Как это у Вас получилось? И в Вашем примере метод private print() у класса B, при вызове его из С, также ругается компилятор, что извини друг, метод у B приватный.

Comment: @SteFFun а вы уверены, что у вас код именно так выглядит? [Вот пример](https://goo.gl/nfhBj6) того, что это работает.

Comment: Я не мог получить доступ к приватным членам класса B, потому что обращался напрямую без super, это моя ошибка. Все логично, тогда правильно ли я понимаю, что в такой ситуации, когда 2 класса вложены в другой и один наследует другого, то по сути все три класса видят приватные члены друг друга?

Comment: @SteFFun да. В этом можно убедиться на [примере](https://goo.gl/hXkXEP).

Comment: Теперь все встало на свои места, спасибо.